# Optimization procedure with parallelization

Tags: python, optimization

I can run 20 calculations in parallel and single run takes approx. 30min-1h.
I wanted to optimize my model with 2-5 parameters taking advantage of the parallelization.

I am dealing with float parameters and run calculations on external server.

I.e. I am looking for optimization procedure which based on the output of these 20 calculations gives me a new 20 variations and conduct this in loop.

Is there a Python optimization procedure where you can do something like this?